# Edicion de Imagenes .net core 6 C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, core

Después de Varios Intentos y Prueba y Error, Logre tomar una imagen, convertirla, subirla a la Base de datos y logre también bajarla y mostrarla, todo eso OK, no hay problema.
Pero la situación se presenta a la hora de hacer **EDICIÓN** del registro, por que si bien logro mostrar la imagen a la hora de querer editar alguno campos de un registro al volver al Controller, el compilador me reclama que el objeto no esta instanciado **(if (file.FileName != null))**, lo cual no me deja avanzar en la ejecución del código.
Aca les presento el código html, donde muestro y también donde hago la captura de la posible nueva imagen:

```
 <td class="text-center">
  <label>Foto</label>
    <img src="data:image /jpg; base64, @Model.Imagen" style="max-height: 20vh;
       object-fit:contain;" name="Foto" />
 </td>
 <td class="text-center">
   <label>Seleccionar Una Imagen</label>
   <div class="input-group flex-nowrap">
     <span class="input-group-text" id="addon-wrapping">
        <i class="fa-regular fa-image"></i></span>
     <input type="file" name="Foto" accept=".gif, .jpg, .jpeg, .png"
      aria-describedby="addon-wrapping"
      placeholder="Inserte Una Imagen"
      title="Seleccione Una Imagen" />
   </div>
</td>
```

y Acá les inserto el código del controller

```
[HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public IActionResult EditEmple(Empleado empleado, IFormFile file)
        {
            try
            {
                if (empleado.RutEmpleado != null)
                {
                    if (file.FileName != null)
                    {
                        byte[] bytes;
                        using (Stream fs = file.OpenReadStream())
                        {
                            using (BinaryReader br = new(fs))
                            {
                                bytes = br.ReadBytes((int)fs.Length);
                                empleado.Imagen = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    // Fin de Conversion de Imagen
                    _context.ModEmpleado(empleado.IdEmpleado, empleado.RutEmpleado, empleado.Nombre, empleado.ApePat, empleado.ApeMat, empleado.IdDepto,
                         empleado.IdCarg, empleado.Anexo, empleado.EmailEmp, empleado.UserName, empleado.Password, empleado.ConfPassWord, empleado.FechaIncorporacion,
                         empleado.IdEmpresa, empleado.IdTipoRemu, empleado.IdAfp, empleado.IdSalud, empleado.ValAdic, empleado.IdSexo, empleado.IdNac,
                         empleado.IdBanco, empleado.IdTipCta, empleado.NumCta, empleado.CallePje, empleado.NumCasa, empleado.VillPobl, empleado.IdCom,
                         empleado.IdProv, empleado.FonoPart, empleado.Email, empleado.FechaNacimiento, empleado.Imagen, empleado.PersonaEmergencia,
                         empleado.FonoEmergencia, empleado.FechaDespido);
                    TempData["successMessage"] = "Datos Actualizados Correctamente";
                    return RedirectToAction("Index");
                }
                else
                {
                    TempData["errorMessage"] = "Problema de Actualización, Revise!";
                    return RedirectToAction("Index");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                TempData["errorMessage"] = ex.Message;
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
        }
```

Entonces, la Pregunta es Alguien podría indicarme como puedo validar el hecho de que si la imagen viene vaciá, por el hecho que no se hizo ningún cambio, pueda pasar por la pregunta sin problema.
Gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No evalues el `file.FileName` sino directamente el `file`

```
if (file != null)
```

El  valor el `FileName` es irrelevante puesto que no lo usas nunca. Esto también es válido para la creación de Empleado.
El `file` directamente estará en `null` si no se seleccionó ningún archivo

Comment: vale, gracias, pero entonces como evalúo si el usuario cambio o no, la foto por una nueva???

Comment: Si el usuario no ha agregado ningún nuevo archivo entonces no está tratando de editarlo, recibe null desde la UI y no actualizes ese campo en BD

Comment: saludos, Gracias, lo que hice fue preguntar en el SP si el valor de imagen esta null, si es asi, que modificara los otros campos y no el null, else modifique todo, gracias por la ayuda y consejos

Answer (score 0):

Evidentemente tienes que comprobar si `if (file != null)`, pero más allá de eso, te presento algunos concejos:

**1.- Uso del operador `?`**

Por ejemplo tu tienes

```
if (empleado.RutEmpleado != null)
```

Supongamos que `empleado` puede ser `null`, entonces tendrías que hacer esto

```
if (empleado !=null && empleado.RutEmpleado != null)
```

Imagina tuvieras que comprobar 10 objetos anidados (una locura), para eso usas el `?`

```
if (empleado?.RutEmpleado != null)
```

---

**2.- Sobre anidación del `if`**

Si tu tienes esta situación

```
if (empleado.RutEmpleado != null)
{
   //mucho codigo
}
else{
  return algo;
}
```

Debes invertir la condición del `if`, lo que te ahorra una indicación, ya que el `else` no es necesari

```
if (empleado.RutEmpleado == null)
{
   return algo;
}
//mucho codigo
```

---

**3.- Múltiples `using`**

Cuando tienes muchos `using` consecutivos, no es necesario anidarlos todos

Esto

```
byte[] bytes;
using (Stream fs = file.OpenReadStream())
{
   using (BinaryReader br = new(fs))
   {
      bytes = br.ReadBytes((int)fs.Length);
      empleado.Imagen = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
   }
}
```

Se puede escribir como:

```
using (Stream fs = file.OpenReadStream())
using (BinaryReader br = new(fs))
{
    byte[] bytes = br.ReadBytes((int)fs.Length);
    empleado.Imagen = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
}
```

---

**4.- Pasar como argumento el objeto y no cada una de sus propiedades**

Esto que tu tienes:

```
 _context.ModEmpleado(empleado.IdEmpleado, empleado.RutEmpleado, empleado.Nombre, empleado.ApePat, empleado.ApeMat, empleado.IdDepto,
                         empleado.IdCarg, empleado.Anexo, empleado.EmailEmp, empleado.UserName, empleado.Password, empleado.ConfPassWord, empleado.FechaIncorporacion,
                         empleado.IdEmpresa, empleado.IdTipoRemu, empleado.IdAfp, empleado.IdSalud, empleado.ValAdic, empleado.IdSexo, empleado.IdNac,
                         empleado.IdBanco, empleado.IdTipCta, empleado.NumCta, empleado.CallePje, empleado.NumCasa, empleado.VillPobl, empleado.IdCom,
                         empleado.IdProv, empleado.FonoPart, empleado.Email, empleado.FechaNacimiento, empleado.Imagen, empleado.PersonaEmergencia,
                         empleado.FonoEmergencia, empleado.FechaDespido);
```

Es una locura total, pasa el ebjeto entero. Para eso obviamente debes editar tu función `ModEmpleado`

```
 _context.ModEmpleado(empleado);
```

---

**5.- Evaluar si ha editado la imagen**

En uno de tus comentarios, dices que quieres comprobar si se ha cambiado la imagen o no. No te sirve comprobar el nombre, 2 imágenes diferentes pueden perfectamente tener el mismo nombre. En la práctica no existe un forma "fácil" de comprobar esta situación.

Lo que conviene hacer en este caso, es siempre pisar la imagen. Es decir cada vez que `file` sea distinto a null, tu la guardas como si se estuviera editando, aunque sea la misma.

---

Código con las mejoras

```js
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public IActionResult EditEmple(Empleado empleado, IFormFile file)
{
    if(empleado?.RutEmpleado == null)
    {
        TempData["errorMessage"] = "Problema de Actualización, Revise!";
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    if (file?.FileName != null)
    {
        using (Stream fs = file.OpenReadStream())
        using (BinaryReader br = new(fs))
        {
            byte[] bytes = br.ReadBytes((int)fs.Length);
            empleado.Imagen = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        }
    }

    try
    {
        _context.ModEmpleado(empleado);
        TempData["successMessage"] = "Datos Actualizados Correctamente";
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        TempData["errorMessage"] = ex.Message;
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
}
```

Comment: Gracias por tus comentarios y consejos, lo he seguido, pero al usar _context.ModEmpleado(empleado); y en el context modifique de la siguiente manera;    public void ModEmpleado(Empleado empleado)
    {
        Database.ExecuteSql($"SP_UPD_EMPL {empleado}");
    } , pero al probar me envia en umesaje de error : -  $exception {"The current provider doesn't have a store type mapping for properties of type 'Empleado'."} System.InvalidOperationException
Gracias

Comment: Gracias por los comentarios y sugerencia, los he seguido. he modificado a:  _context.ModEmpleado(empleado); y en el context lo deje de la siguiente manera:     public void ModEmpleado(Empleado empleado)
    {
        Database.ExecuteSql($"SP_UPD_EMPL {empleado}");
    };  pero me envia el sguiente mensaje:  {"The current provider doesn't have a store type mapping for properties of type 'Empleado'."}